# how to get current size of a subview when device size changes in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, view-bound

I have to view: view_1 and view_2 . view_1 height is proportional to the main view controller height and I am adding view_2 programmatically as a subview of view_1 with a proportional height.

**Problem**

when the device size changes say from iPhone 6 to iPhone 5, the view_1 adjust correctly but its height I am passing to a function to draw its subview view_2 is still what was set in interface builder and so it is out of bounds in iPhone 4 moving from iPhone 6

Thus I want to know how can I get the correct size of a view that what resize automatically to fit the current device?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The size of the view isn't established until *Auto Layout* runs.  Your first opportunity to get the correct size is in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    // access view size here
}
```

---

Here's a complete example that adds a second view as a subview of the first view.  The red view was added in the Storyboard; it is centered horizontally and vertically and it's height/width is 50% of its superview.

The yellow view is added programmatically.  It's frame is computed from the frame of the red view to be 50% of the width of the red view.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var view1: UIView!
    var view2: UIView?

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        if view2 == nil {
            view2 = UIView()
            view2?.backgroundColor = .yellowColor()
            view1.addSubview(view2!)
        }

        let width = view1.frame.size.width
        let height = view1.frame.size.height

        let frame = CGRect(x: width * 0.25, y: height * 0.25, width: width * 0.5, height: height * 0.5)

        view2?.frame = frame
    }
}
```

Not that `viewDidLayoutSubviews` gets called multiple times, so you must take care not to add `view2` every time it is called.  That is why the code checks to see if `view2` has been added.

---

[image: iPhone 4s Simulator Portrait]

---

[image: iPhone 5s Simulator Landscape]

---

[image: iPhone 5s Rotation exmaple]

Comment: Still getting the old size set in interface builder :-/ .

Comment: Are you sure you did an override of `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and not `viewWillLayoutSubviews`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,you can find the screen size of device.

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
let screenWidth = screenSize.width
let screenHeight = screenSize.height
```

Comment: I don't want the screen size but the size of the subview in the device when its size change and the subview size is adjusted by the system

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this in Viewdidload
First you need to set view one frame

```
view_1.frame = CGRectMake(0 , 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)
```

then set frame of view_2

```
view_2.frame = CGRectMake(0 , 0, view_1.frame.width, view_1.frame.height)
```